# Air application developed with Flex stops unexpectedly on Android 2.2.x

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

I'm developing an Android application using Flex (ver 4.5). I can run it perfectly on Android 2.3.x and above but when it comes to Android 2.2.x my app stops unexpectedly.
I wonder if there is any thing I should do for it to work on older versions of Android?